# Neo4j Index Lookup using Neo4J-REST-PHP-API-client

Tags: php, indexing, lookup, neo4j

I am unable to get the Index Lookup to work with the PHP API Client.

First, am creating a node and am indexing it. This works fine. Then when I test the lookup

```
curl -H Accept:application/json http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/my_nodes/guid/108
```

I get:

```
[ {
  "indexed" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/index/node/my_nodes/guid/108/57",
  "outgoing_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/57/relationships/out",
  "data" : {
    "guid" : 108,
    "title" : "New User ABC",
    "owner_guid" : "2"
  },
  "traverse" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/57/traverse/{returnType}",
  "all_typed_relationships" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/57/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}",
  "property" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/57/properties/{key}",
  "self" : "http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/57", ....
```

So far so good. However, when I define a function as follows in the PHP API client to perform a lookup.

```
public function getNodeByKey ($key, $value) 
{ 
    $uri = $this->base_uri . 'index/node/my_nodes/' . $key . '/' . $value ;
    list($response, $http_code) = HTTPUtil::jsonGetRequest($uri); 
    if ($http_code == 200) 
        return Node::inflateFromResponse($this, $response);
    else { 
        throw new HttpException($http_code);
    } 
}
```

and following is how am calling the above function:

```
$graphDb = new GraphDatabaseService('http://localhost:7474/db/data/');
...
$node = $graphDb->getNodeByKey ('guid', $uid);              
$relationship = $node->createRelationshipTo($another_node, 'works with');
$relationship->save();
```

I get a HTTP response of 200 from getNodeByKey(). However, When I try to save the relationship, I get a 404. I tried using the dump_node () to test and the node I tried to lookup i.e. $node was null. I cannot figure out where am going wrong. Any pointers ?

Thanks in advance,
Nanda

Answer (score 0):

Nanda, could you try to get the indexed node out using curl also, according to http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api.html ?

Comment: Pete, Yes, I was able to access the node using the index using curl but was not able to get it to work with the PHP API client. However, I figured out the problem. I will post the answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get this to work using the PHP API client. I had to modify the function inflateFromResponse to the following. I am not sure if its a problem with the version of neo4j am using (viz 1.2)

```
public static function inflateFromResponse($neo_db, $response)
{

    $node = new Node($neo_db);
    $node->_is_new = FALSE;
    $node->_id = end(explode("/", $response[0]['self']));
    $node->setProperties($response[0]['data']);

    return $node;
}
```